# How to place custom template (phtml) file in local module direcotry instead of default template directory

Tags: magento-1.9, module, phtml

I am creating a new module for my Magento project where I have a few template files which get appended to `>catalog_product_view catalog_category_default` `checkout_cart_index` and few other pages.

Currently, I have placed my module configuration file in `design/fontend/base/default/layout/modulename_subfolder.xml` and template file is placed at

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/modulename/subfolder/my_product_view.phtml
```

I want to move this XML and phtml files to `local/modulename/subfolder`

I have tried creating the same folder structure in my module folder but it didn't work

design/fontend/base/default/layout/modulename_subfolder.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="modulename_subfolder_product_view_block" template="modulename/subfolder/my_catalog_product_view.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

In Magento 1, module code (Models, Blocks, configuration etc) goes in `app/code/local/` or `app/code/community`, frontend template files go in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template` and frontend layout files go in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout`.

Yes, this means modules are not self-contained and end up scattered through the Magento filesystem. It's one of the major shortcomings of Magento 1 and was thankfully rectified in Magento 2. There are workarounds including [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) which is used extensively by extension developers, but they are only workarounds and don't fix the situation.